# When are new Shadow Broker recordings shown?

Tags: mass-effect-2

At the end of the [Lair of the Shadow Broker](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Lair_of_the_Shadow_Broker) DLC (which was awesome!), you are shown various security camera recordings. The narration indicates that more recordings will be available later.

When is *later*? Is it based on your progress in the rest of the Mass Effect 2 story? Or a real-world timer, maybe based on how close we are to the release of Mass Effect 3? Or does it depend on Bioware releasing new content for it arbitrarily?

Comment: It's not based on a real-world timer.

Answer (score 2):

I think more recordings are shown on your second visit to the Shadow's Broker ship. I think it isn't enough to just go back to the Normandy, then back to the ship, but I could be wrong on that.

When I played through Mass Effect 2 on a second character, I did the DLC relatively early in the game (well before the end of the main quest). I happened to go back to the ship later in the game to see if anything had changed, and new recordings were available.

If I had to guess, traveling to another system, landing, and traveling back should be enough to trigger the second set of recordings.